# Regex True Match Behavior

Tags: php, regex, match, router

I'm trying to do a router with true match using regex but I'm always stuck in how routes are loaded.

If I have routes like

- /:any
- /blog/:any
- /blog/category/:any

The first route will always come true instead of using second route or third.

```
$data = array();

foreach($this->routes as $route => $rData) {

    if(strpos($route, ':') !== false) {
        foreach($this->tokens as $token => $value) {
            $route = str_replace($token, $value, $route);
        }
    }

    if(preg_match('#^'.$route.'$#', $url, $matches)) {
        $data['params'] = array_slice($matches, 1);
        $data = array_merge($rData, $data);
        break;
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
$routes = array(
    '/:any' => callback,
    '/blog/:any' => callback,
    '/blog/category/:any' => callback
);
```

Tokens:

```
$tokens = array(
    ':num' => '([0-9]+)',
    ':any' => '(.+)'
);
```

Url:

```
$url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

How can I do regex / preg_match to get the correct route match?

Comment: It might be helpful to show how `$this->routes`,  `$this->tokens` and `$url` are getting populated, or at least example values for all of those variables to get a better idea what is happening.

Comment: I think is straight forward how things are but I've added those too.

Answer (score 0):

usually, in such cases route rules should be written in such a way that the following be more general than the previous one. They do work **for the first match**

Yoy should write them so:

```
$routes = array(
    '/blog/category/:any' => callback
    '/blog/:any' => callback,
    '/:any' => callback,
);
```

This is not an error of a code. It is simply the logic of execution

**UPDATE**  born out of discussions with the author of the question

Suppose that we want to find a match with the largest amount of segments:

```
$routes = array(
    '/:any' => 'callback1',
    '/blog/:any' => 'callback2',
    '/blog/category/:any' => 'callback'
);

foreach ($routes as $in => $out) 
    $counts[$in] = count(explode('/', $in)); 
arsort($counts);
foreach ($counts as $in => $count) 
    $newroutes[$in] = $routes[$in];

var_dump($newroutes);
```

returns

```
array(3) {
  ["/blog/category/:any"]=>
  string(8) "callback"
  ["/blog/:any"]=>
  string(9) "callback2"
  ["/:any"]=>
  string(9) "callback1"
}
```

then use this `newroutes` array

Comment: True but if you are in a module situation you wont have control how modules are installed. For example if module category is installed after blog, blog routes will overwrite category routes. 

There must be a solution for this.

Comment: @Filipe What I wrote is a practice used in many cms. Else  if you walk along the routes and  will find 10 matches, which of them you will perform. Have you the answer?

Comment: @Filipe If a module wants to add route dynamically it should not extend the previous pathes but make own such as `/auth`, for example

Comment: I know that other cms work like that but IMHO it is wrong and we should control how things work. 

One partial solution is **array_reverse**

Regarding your second comment I don't agree because if you have two modules, accounts and galleries, where account can have a gallery then you will have an dynamic route and you should be able to control it.

So if accounts gives you **/accounts/:username**, gallery should be able to add something like **/accounts/:username/gallery**

Comment: Then answer my 1st question - what will  you take from 10 matches? What is the rule?

Comment: If you have 10 equal matches then that's bad coding. Now router should be able to read and exploit url string and remove dynamic variables (:any/:num) and compare the static variables and that is how you should get true matching behavior and not using test/trial to find out which route / callback to use or not call first dynamic variable found.

Comment: I think we do not understand each other. Input url /blog/category/news matches all rules. You want take the longest? If yes. I know the answer

Comment: Lets go the longest if it is the only way.